# unallocated space in hard drives causing windows not to load

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, hardware-failure

I was trying to dual boot kubuntu with windows 8. Now, I created unallocated space and restarted my PC, the windows didn't load showing an error. Windows diagnostics didn't work. There partitions in between two unallocated spaces which might be causing problem. How to fix it?

Comment: What was your partition setup like before making changes and how does it look like now?

Comment: If you want help you will need to tell us the exact error you recieve.  Why would you create a partition between two regions of unallocated space on your hdd?

Answer (score 0):

I would first try to format the first unallocated partition to any format and reinstall grub with a linux live session choosing the first partition to save the grub loader on.

let me know if it works there are many more methods. but that is the easiest and most successful.

Comment: don't forget to mention the chainloader entry for windows :)